How to configure VS Code SFTP extension to work with 1Password SSH agent?
I'm trying to set up a new development environment using VS Code connecting to a DigitalOcean Droplet and use SFTP to sync files between my local machine and the remote server. However, I keep receiving the "All configured authentication methods failed" error when trying to connect. Specifically I'm using 1Password as my SSH Agent to host the SSH key and trying to refer to it.
Does anyone know the correct parameters to use for the sftp.json file to get this to work?
For reference, the following is working in my .ssh/config file to connect via SSH.
Host *
    IdentityAgent "~/{...}.1password/t/agent.sock"
    
Host {IP Address}
    HostName {IP Address}
    User {username}

However, when I go to try to connect using the SFTP extension in VS Code, it does not work. The sftp.json file is as follows:
{
    "name": "Digital Ocean",
    "host": "{IP Address}",
    "protocol": "sftp",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "{username}",
    "remotePath": "/",
    "agent": "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK",
    "uploadOnSave": false,
    "useTempFile": false,
    "openSsh": false
}

The error response I receive back is: All configured authentication methods failed.
I did try listing the identities for the agent in terminal and receive the following:
% ssh-add -l
256 SHA256:[...] (Digital Ocean)

